# Form submit does not submit partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a main page which looks like:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %> 
    <% 
     using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Customer", FormMethod.Get))
    { %>
     <%Html.RenderPartial("Attributes", "Shared");%> 
     <%=Html.TextBox("Name") %> 
     <%=Html.TextBox("Area") %>
     <%= Html.SubmitButton("Submit", "Click Submit")%>
<% } %>
```

The corresponding controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult Submit(FormCollection collection)
{

//Form collection is null. 

}
```

The Get request URL does not contain the PartialView fields. It contains the main page fields though. How do I ensure that the Partial views also get submitted?

Also, why is FormCollection null?

UPDATE:

The partial view looks like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Cenovus.EquipList.Web" %>

<select id="Attribute1"><option value="-1"> Default</option>

</select>

<select id="Attribute2"><option value="-1"> Default</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the partial view? And the reason that FormCollection is null is because it is a collection of forms, not form elements. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formcollection.aspx

Comment: Assign name attribute to the select boxex in partial view and try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the name property on your form elements to get them to show up in your collection of form values.